# Formatting Gmail messages fetched using the Google API in Node.js

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client, hbs

I am using the Google API library in Node.js to fetch emails from Gmail. The code snippet below demonstrates how I retrieve and extract data from the fetched message:

```
const gmail = google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth: oAuth2Client });
const messageId = req.params.id;

const message = await gmail.users.messages.get({
  userId: "me",
  id: messageId,
  format: "full",
});

// Extract the required data from the message
const isRead = !message.data.labelIds.includes("UNREAD");
const snippet = message.data.snippet.trim();
const email = {
  id: message.data.id,
  subject: message.data.payload.headers.find(
    (header) => header.name === "Subject"
  ).value,
  from: message.data.payload.headers
    .find((header) => header.name === "From")
    .value.split("<")[0],
  date: moment(
    message.data.payload.headers.find((header) => header.name === "Date").value
  ).format("MM/DD/YYYY, hh:mm a"),
  snippet,
  isRead,
  message: Buffer.from(message.data.payload.parts[0].body.data,
          "base64").toString("utf-8"),
};
```

The above code successfully fetches the email, and extracts essential information such as the subject, sender, date, and message content. However, the extracted **message** is in raw format, and I'm unable to preserve the original formatting and layout seen in the Gmail interface.

I want to render the email with the same design that users see when they access Gmail through the web interface or the official app. How can I achieve this formatting for the fetched messages?

Any insights or suggestions on how to improve the code to achieve the desired Gmail-like formatting would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you getting the mail as html? and also are you getting the css in the style tag ?

Comment: Nope, how can I get the HTML and the CSS in the response?

Comment: I have not used the gmail api but I have used IMAP for receiving mails, in IMAP you get the mail both as string and html format. So check the gmail api if any option is there so that you get the message as html

Comment: I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428246/retrieve-email-message-body-in-html-using-gmail-api), check if it helps